# How can I make it so the eyelid like objects properly work?

Tags: rigging, shrinkwrap

Ive been doing blender for a little bit, and have been working on a Robot rig. I recentyl decided I wish for said robot to have 'eye lids.' which are basically 2 planes that can move backwards and dissapear into the mesh when needed. Or, Ive tried to. Ive tried useing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko0Wq0MZO8E) tutorial, as well as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XleNIUWoydY) tutorial, yet I have been unable to get this to work. I found that I could use shrink wrap in the object mode to get the desired results, but could not do so when rigging. Any advice, or tutorials, that I could follow to fix this issue?

[image: eyelids closed, default position]
[image: eyelids open, default position]
[image: eyelids closed, model moved via rig]

Comment: If you can't get a lattice to work, I'd be inclined to use Shape keys for that although I'm no expert. There's a basic tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B11XBZmIIZc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the *Boolean* modifier?

Make two eyelids for each eye. These are just two round planes that cover the eyes. The inner faces are duplicated and scaled up a little. The top and the bottom eyelids are stacked and cover the eye. In the example, a mirror modifier is used but it's recommended to make them individual objects:

[image: eyelids]

Then create two cubes for each eye and place them over the eyelid planes. (In the example, a mirror modifier was used for laziness). Place one cube at the top and one at the bottom of the eye.

Then add a *Boolean* modifier to the eyelid plane. Use *Intersect* and *Fast*, and the control cube as the boolean object for the settings of the *Boolean* modifier.

[image: boolean modifier and helper objects]

Then you can control the cubes that control the eyelids:

[image: animation]

Comment: That actually works perfectly! Thank you a lot for this. Idk why I didn't think of adding a Boolean modifier earlier. I hope you have a great day you cool person!